# Silo structure on magazine site

Tags: html, wordpress, nofollow, theme

I will have to code magazine theme using silo structure.
Requirements of the design is to display most recent posts of each category on the home page, popular/last commented posts in the sidebar etc etc..

I cant think of anything else than setting nofollow attribute to each of mentioned links. But by doing so, on the home page for example i will have 50-80 nofollow links...

Will that actually hurt SEO? What are your suggestions?

Comment: `I will have 50-80 nofollow links` I hope those are external links. `rel=nofollow` was changed by Google to work externally many years ago and using internally is considered attempting to manipulate flow.

Comment: They would be internal links. Any other solution?

Comment: Well it'll help if you tell us why you was going to use nofollow in the first place? nofollow doesn't mean Google won't follow the links, its an external attribute.

Comment: Because i will have to somehow "mask" links displayed on the home page in order to achieve silo structure. As i stated above, requirements of the design is to display most recent posts of each category on the home page, which will ruin silo structure.. right?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want links to particular posts in categories on your homepage when using silo structure? This will ruin your silo  as you would interconnect your siloed structure instead of isolating to specific content groups.

Try to outline your silo structure like this:

Homepage

- Category Page 1

  - Related Post 1
  - Related Post 2
    ...
- Category Page 2

  - Related Post 1
    ...

[etc]

Consider Silo/Category Pages as (separated from each other) containers for different related keyword/content groups.

You want to rank your Category Pages strongly for wider spectrum of keywords as their strong relevance will flow upwards to the homepage.

Therefore you optimise Category Pages for higher traffic/difficulty keywords and link them with homepage with high importance links from navigation menu.

Then you follow linking category posts to category pages as in tiers (again broader keyword selection, LSI & long tail keywords) this will shape your pagerank flow up towards homepage through content relevance (where you rank against tough competition with 1-3 high traffic/volume/value keywords)

Build your link structure downwards in siloed tiers & at the same time shape your content relevance spectrum for each siloed tier. It's very similar to tiered link building just happens within one domain.

Link:

1. from homepage navigation to category pages
2. from category pages to category related posts
3. between category pages

If you link like you've described from homepage straight to bottom (category posts) you will dilute your relevance flow with too broad keyword spectrum linking to your home page.

Therefore you're more likely to get less relevance points from google then sites with strongly focused anchor flow in their internal links structure.

Comment: First of all thanks for the input. As i said it is 'magazine' theme and requirements of such design is to display most recent posts of each category on the homepage. Design is already approved and there is no going back. That why i want to use nofollow on such links, but i have no idea if using a lot of nofollow links will actually hurt site.

Comment: In this Matt Cutts video you will find the answer ;) "How many links on a page should we have?": http://youtu.be/QHG6BkmzDEM

Comment: Hmm this is not about how many links i should have on a page, I need a strategy/whatever to accomplish silo structure with given design of the site :)